# Is there a way to set the default alignment for mathtools matrices?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices, mathtools

I have a lot of `mathtools` matrices in my document that require right alignment (and others that have other alignment):

```
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  7 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix*}
...
```

The `mathtools` documentation explains that the `smallmatrix` environment allows the default alignment to be changed using `smallmatrix-align=<c,l,r>`. Is there such an option/command for changing the default alignment of display style matrices?

Comment: so you don't want to provide the option then is that right?

Comment: @percusse I would still like to have the option to have matrices with center-/left- alignment, etc., if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some magic!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\patcher[1]{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname#1*\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\p@tcher\csname#1*\endcsname
  }%
}
\newcommand\p@tcher[4]{\unexpanded{#1#2#3}{r}}
\makeatother

\patcher{bmatrix} % repeat for the other matrix types you need

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix*}
111 & 11 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 11
\end{bmatrix*}
+
\begin{bmatrix*}[c]
111 & 11 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 11
\end{bmatrix*}
+
\begin{bmatrix*}[l]
111 & 11 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 11
\end{bmatrix*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The magic exploits the fact that the definition of `bmatrix*` and friends is essentially the same; the macro `\bmatrix*` (only available through `\csname`) expands to

```
\MH_nospace_protected_testopt:n \bmatrix* \\bmatrix* {c}
```

(six tokens). So the inner macro `\p@tcher` changes the fourth argument to `{r}` and `\patcher` rebuilds the macro with the new replacement text.

Comment: Does this solution also allow me to override the alignment option as necessary? e.g. the default alignment is `[r]`, but I can set specific matrices to have `[c]` or `[l]` alignment? Or would I need to create a separate macro for the original `\bmatrix` command?

Comment: @Alex You can use the optional argument as before. The patch just modifies the default choice